# How to use interfaces from IE9 Beta library?

Tags: c++, atl, bho, internet-explorer-9

I asked similar question at [Internet Explorer Extension Development Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/b4c23859-330b-4736-abe5-d4b230b5e752) but didn't get the answer. I found that not only me has this [problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/0bbd9c7c-b18e-4318-a318-eab2b17d295e)

Did anyone used any of [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974374%28VS.85%29.aspx) interfaces from IE9 Beta?
I'm querying for `IHTMLDocument7` using ATL but I get NULL pointer

```
CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument7> document7 = document3;
if(document7)
{
//do sth with document7
}
```

but document7 is NULL. Other interfaces (IHTMLDocument1-6) works fine.

Comment: Is the document in question running in IE9 standards mode?

Comment: Yes it is. It depends on which page I am. But for example google is in IE9 standard mode and this pointer is still NULL.
This question was also asked to me on IE forum. Do you have any other ideas that weren't suggested there that might help me?

Comment: This problem is fixed in IE9 RC.